# How can I update a clean install of Acrobat Professional 8.0.0 to the latest version?

Tags: updates, certificate, adobe-acrobat

When I do a clean install of Acrobat Pro 8.0.0 on my system and attempt to check for updates from the help menu I get an error about "unable to check for updates for Adobe Updater".

Adobe provides manual update files on their website, but there are almost a dozen of these and they must be installed in the correct sequence or they will not work.

How can I make the built-in updater in Acrobat Pro 8.0.0 work today?

Comment: Why would you want to use a product that isn't updated anymore?

Comment: Because Creative Cloud is expensive.

Comment: Acrobat Pro XI isn't really if you have a previous version.  I upgraded for only $100 but I had 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by an expired certificate that the updater uses when attempting to look for updates. You can work around this problem by setting the date on your computer to August 1st, 2011.

There is a range of dates that work but this one is known good. When this is done you can check for updates in Acrobat and it will find an update and install it. After several iterations of this (and at least one reboot) you will make it to the 8.1.7 patch, which includes a new updater that does not have the expired certificate problem. At this time you can set your system clock back to the correct time and continue with the new updater until you reach the newest release.

Things to be aware of:

1. Some systems may auto-reset the clock to the correct time if it is off (even if disabled in Windows); keep an eye on it and make sure that it doesn't change on you when doing the first few rounds of updates.
2. Shut down as many cloud services as you can while doing these updates (game clients, file syncing services, etc) and don't browse the internet. Even though pretending that it's 2011 makes Acrobat's certificate happy, it invalidates a lot of certificates for modern applications. You want to minimize the certificate errors you accumulate in other applications that may cause headaches later.